# как сделать, чтобы два блока зависили от друг друга? html css js

Tags: javascript, css, html

Как сделать так, чтобы блок1 изменял высоту до размеров блока2? (зависил от блока2)

```
article > #content > .layout-news {
 display: flex;
 width: 80%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 20px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px;

 border: solid 3px red;
}

article > #content > .layout-news > .layout-news_banner {
 border-radius: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
 background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
 margin: auto 1%;
 padding-bottom: 30px;

 border: solid 3px red;
}
<div class="layout-news layout-news_style-text">
        <aside class="layout-news_banner">
            <img src="img/layout-news_1.jpg">
            <h2>Котя уснул, выполняя ДЗ</h2>
            <p>"Здоровый сон важнее", - говорит котя</p>
        </aside>
        <aside class="layout-news_banner">
            <img src="img/layout-news_2.jpg">
            <h2>Кот зол, потому что вода</h2>
            <p>Он намочил лапки и готов разорвать ими всех вокруг!
                <br> Даже не понятно, почему <br> и главное как
            </p>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

[image: Блоки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно делать таблицу...

```
<table><tr>
  <td class="layout-news_banner">сюда первую картинку</td>
  <td class="layout-news_banner">Сюда вторую</td>
</tr></table>
```

Её блоки всегда автоматически принимают одинаковый размер. 
И прикрутить к ним `vertical-align: top; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);`

С таблицами - железобетонно, всегда и везде. Но скорее всего тут и просто добавление `height: 100%` прокатило бы, вместо `auto`

Comment: Зависить стал, но теперь при маленьком сужении окна - верстка изображения начинает плыть - картина1, где 1 строка, выше картины2, где 3 строки